# Cannot hard reset

Tags: factory-reset, hard-reset

I have a Mobicel Matrix. After some time using it the screen does not respond to touch. After i click on power it lights up and asks me to draw my pattern, but nothing happens as i draw it, then it goes back to sleep.

I tried a hard factory reset but i'm stuck at clicking the  Options/Menu touch button [=] as it does nothing. 
Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the battery aside for a while, reinsert it and try again. If that doesn't work, it's probably an issue with the touch screen.

Answer (score -1):

If your usb debug is activated you can use ADB commandes to rest you phone ( adb reboot-bootloader )